# Given $(f+g)(x)=10-3x$ and $(f-g)(x)=5x-14$, find $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given $(f+g)(x)=10-3x$ and $(f-g)(x)=5x-14$, find $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

I have no idea where to start, can someone please help me?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You realize that by definition, $(f+g)(x)$ means $f(x)+g(x)$, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition,$$\begin{align*} & (f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)\tag1\\ & (f-g)(x)=f(x)-g(x)\tag2\end{align*}$$
And since the problem states $(f+g)(x)=10-3x$ and $(f-g)(x)=5x-14$, we have$$\begin{align*} & f(x)+g(x)=-3x+10\tag3\\ & f(x)-g(x)=5x-14\tag4\end{align*}$$
Which can be easily solved by adding $(3)$ and $(4)$ together to get$$\begin{align*} & 2f(x)=5x-14-3x+10\tag5\\ & \therefore\boxed{f(x)=x-2}\tag6\end{align*}$$
And substituting $(6)$ back into $(3)$ gives$$\begin{align*} & \color{green}{f(x)}+g(x)=-3x+10\tag7\\ & \color{green}{x-2}+g(x)=-3x+10\tag8\\ & \boxed{g(x)=-4x+12}\tag9\end{align*}$$

Comment: How is it difficult it's a linear system in $f$ and $g$? Just treat $-3x+10$ as "constant" and $5x-14$ as "constant" when solving.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Note the possible sarcasm!

Comment: I could never tell...I don't know if sarcasm would be appropriate, we want the op to know exactly what we mean. @Frank

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla See my new edit...

Comment: Yes, sarcasm should be avoided to avoid confusion.

Comment: @SimpleArt <sigh> I removed the sarcasm...

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

What happens if you sum those two results together? Or what if you subtract them?